# Includes and Linking in C

Tags: c, compilation, linker, pthreads, header-files

I'm solving a simple Readers/Writers problem. I have 3 `.c` files and 3 `.h` files.

`parent.c`:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include "parent.h"
#include "reader.h"
#include "writer.h"



 int main(){
      printf("Aeeeee ");
      globalVariable = 0;
      readers = 0;  
      max = 25;
      sem_init(&waitSema, 0, 0);
      sem_init(&globalSema, 0, 0);
      sem_init(&rdSema, 0, 0);
      pthread_t * array [max];  
      int mda = 0;
      int i;
      for(i = 0; i < max; i++){
        pthread_t * thr = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));
        array[i] = thr;
        mda = rand()%100;
        if(mda > 50){
          pthread_create(array[i], NULL, writer, NULL);
        }else{
          pthread_create(array[i], NULL, reader, NULL);
        }
      }

      for(i=0; i<max; i++){
        pthread_join(*array[i], NULL);
      }

   }
```

`reader.c`:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include "reader.h"
#include "parent.h"

void * reader (void * param){
  sem_wait(&waitSema);
  sem_wait(&rdSema);
  if(readers == 0){
    sem_wait(&globalSema);
  }
  readers++;
  sem_post(&rdSema);
  sem_post(&waitSema);
  printf("Reader : %d\n", globalVariable);
  sem_wait(&rdSema);
  readers--;
  if(readers == 0){
    sem_post(&globalSema);
  }
  sem_post(&rdSema);
}
```

`writer.c`:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include "writer.h"
#include "parent.h"

void * writer (void * param){
  sem_wait(&waitSema);
  sem_wait(&globalSema);
  sem_post(&waitSema);
  globalVariable++;
  printf("Writer : %d\n", globalVariable);
  sem_post(&globalSema);
}
```

`parent.h`:

```
sem_t waitSema;         
sem_t globalSema;       
sem_t rdSema;

int globalVariable;     
int readers;        
int max;
```

`reader.h`:

```
void * reader (void * param);
```

`writer.h`:

```
void * writer (void * param);
```

I compile the code with this command:  `gcc -pthread parent.c reader.c writer.c -o out`, but when I run `./out` nothing happens. The `main` function from `parent.c` doesn't execute.

What I want to do is declare some global variables in `parent.h` in order to use them in all 3 `.c` files.

Comment: How do you know that main function from parent.c doesn't execute?

Comment: I inserted `printf` in the first line of main.

Comment: You never initialise your variables. `max` might very well be negative, meaning the `for` loop never runs even once.

Comment: I think the problem is in linking 3 files.

Comment: When i use all this code just in one .c file it works, but seperatly it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in semaphore initialization. 
At first I gave `0`s as a value to semaphores and because of it all threads couldn't join in the end. But after I changed values to `1`s, everything worked as it should.

```
sem_init(&waitSema, 0, 1);
sem_init(&globalSema, 0, 1);
sem_init(&rdSema, 0, 1);
```

Thanks everyone for answers.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`extern`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_variable) keyword.

header.h file:

```
  /* notify code that this symbol exists, but isn't declared yet */
  extern int someInt;
```

.c file 1:

```
  /* declare symbol */
  int someInt = 0;
```

.c file 2:

```
  #include <header.h>
  /* you can use `someInt` now */
```